# phpExcel doesn't set column width auto

Tags: html, phpexcel

I am builiding an excel file using phpExcel. I fill all the cells I need and at last I set some formatting on the excel file. One of the things I'm doing is to adjust the cell width but I am getting a strange result. None of the columns are set to the right width. Some are set to a larger width and the other are left to the original width. I don't use bold font anywhere but just some background color on the first row. 
This is my actual code for formatting:

```
$header = 'A1:EK1';
$ews->getStyle($header)->getFill()->setFillType(\PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('ff00008b');
$style = array(
    'font' => array('bold'  => false,
        'color' => array('rgb' => 'FFFFFF'),
        'size'  => 12,
        'name'  => 'Verdana'),
    'alignment' => array('horizontal' => \PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,),
    );
$ews->getStyle($header)->applyFromArray($style);
for ($col = ord('A'); $col <= ord('HK'); $col++)
{
    $ews->getColumnDimension(chr($col))->setAutoSize(true);
}
```

I have had a look at many questions on SO and googled a bit but I have found issues only in case of csv files (mine is a xlsx) or bold font (I don't have at all). Since I am still learning on how this library works I am looking for some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a column is set to AutoSize, PHPExcel attempts to calculate the column width based on the calculated value of the column (so on the result of any formulae), and any additional characters added by format masks such as thousand separators.

By default, this is an `estimated` width: a more accurate calculation method is available, based on using GD, which can also handle font style features such as bold and italic; but this is a much bigger overhead, so it is turned off by default. You can enable the more accurate calculation using

```
PHPExcel_Shared_Font::setAutoSizeMethod(PHPExcel_Shared_Font::AUTOSIZE_METHOD_EXACT);
```

However, autosize doesn't apply to all Writer formats... CSV files do not support any formatting, just data, so column width (which is formatting) cannot be applied when you write a CSV file

Comment: Thanks. I know! As you see in the question I am writing a xlsx

Comment: Can you help me on how to enable it? I'm not very fond of OOP :)

Answer (score 0):

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension(COLUMN)->setAutoSize(true);